# CodeIgniter : How to upload multiple image into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

So I working with form that can do multiple uploads.

```
This is my database field :
ID
product_picture_1
product_picture_2
product_picture_3
product_picture_4
```

This is my view :

```
<?=form_open_multipart('product/insert_product');?>
   <input type="file" multiple class="default" name="product_picture_1" required/>
   <input type="file" multiple class="default" name="product_picture_2" required/>
   <input type="file" multiple class="default" name="product_picture_3" required/>
   <input type="file" multiple class="default" name="product_picture_4" required/>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is my controller :

```
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
            $config['max_width']  = '25000';
            $config['max_height']  = '20000';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                    $data['product_data'] = $this->product_model->list_product();
                    $data['group_data'] = $this->group_model->list_group();
                    $this->load->view('admin/product_view', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                    foreach($_FILES as $field_name => $file)
                    {
                        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))   
                        {
                                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                                $this->load->view('admin/product_view', $error);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                                $upload_image = $this->upload->data();

                                $data = array (
                                                'group_id' => $this->input->post('group_id'),
                                                'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
                                                'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description'),
                                                'product_picture_1' => $upload_image['file_name'],
                                                'product_picture_2' => $upload_image['file_name'],
                                                'product_picture_3' => $upload_image['file_name'],
                                                'product_picture_4' => $upload_image['file_name']
                                                );

                                $this->product_model->add_product($data);
                                redirect('product');

                        }
                    }
            }
```

and this is my model :

```
    function add_product($data)
    {
            //untuk insert data ke table product
            $this->db->insert('product', $data);
    }
```

My code going wrong, because my product_picture database field full of product_picture_1..
while the rest (product_picture_2, product_picture_3, product_picture_4) are not entered into the database and their fields.

Is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
redirect('product');
```

After the first file is processed, you're redirecting to another page, so the processing of the other elements of the form is cut off.

Comment: and now I get four times processing